# Excel VBA code to capture all file names from Parent Folder into excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am having VBA code to capture all file names into excel from a parent folder,below code works for me to capture only one file format ie.xlsm.
Is there a way to capture multiple format files eg.PDF, JPEG,docx.

Following are VBA code:-

```
Sub getallfiles()

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim parentfolder As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Dim filetype As String
    i = 1
    Filelocation = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\VBA Practice"
    Range("A2").Select
    If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Selection.ClearContents
    End If
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set parentfolder = fso.Getfolder(Filelocation)
    filetype = "*.xlsm*"
    Listallfiles parentfolder,filetype
    For Each folder In parentfolder.Subfolders
        Listallfiles folder, filetype
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `ListAllFiles`? Please edit your question to provie a [MCVE].

Comment: The obvious would be to change your file type parameter.  What have you tried?

Comment: Sub Listallfiles(fld As Object, ftype As Variant, Sh As Works)
    Dim file As Object
    For Each file In fld.Files
        If file.Name Like ftype Then
        ActiveCell.Value = i      
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = file.Name
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = fld.Path
            If Right(fld.Path, 8) = "Treasury" Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "yes"
            Else
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = ""
            End If
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            i = i + 1
        End If
   Next
End Sub

Comment: @Fazil Oleed It is not a good idea to post the code in a comment. If needed/required, please edit your question and place the code there...

Comment: Well Noted Fane Duru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not show us the called function and I tried imagine one able to do what you need. Please, test your code adapted in the next way:

```
Sub getallfiles()
 Dim fso As Object, parentfolder As Object, folder As Object, file As Object
 Dim fileType As Variant, Filelocation As String

 Filelocation = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\VBA Practice" 'please use your real USER...
 Range("A2").Select
 If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
 End If
 Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
 Set parentfolder = fso.GetFolder(Filelocation)
 fileType = Array("xlsm", "pdf", "jpg", "docx") 'put here how many extensions you wang...
 ListAllFiles parentfolder, fileType, ActiveSheet
 For Each folder In parentfolder.SubFolders
     ListAllFiles folder, fileType, ActiveSheet
 Next
End Sub

Sub ListAllFiles(strFold As Object, fileType As Variant, sh As Worksheet)
 Dim fso As Object, objFile As Object, lastR As Long, mtch As Variant
 
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    
    lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
        For Each objFile In strFold.files
           mtch = Application.match(fso.GetExtensionName(objFile.name), fileType, 0)
           If Not IsError(mtch) Then
                sh.Range("A" & lastR).Value = objFile: lastR = lastR + 1
           End If
        Next
End Sub
```

The above code can use some optimization, in order to be faster. A fastest way should be using an array, populating it in the called sub and drop its values at once at the end...

**Edited**:

1. Please declare the next variables on top of the module where the code exists (in the declarations area):

```
Private arrFiles As Variant, iFile As Long
```

2. Copy the  next adapted code in the standard module where you declared the above variables:

```
Sub getallfilesArrray() 
 Dim fso As Object, parentfolder As Object, folder As Object, file As Object
 Dim fileType As Variant, Filelocation As String

 Filelocation = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\VBA Practice"
 Range("A2").CurrentRegion.ClearContents

 Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
 iFile = 1
 ReDim arrFiles(1 To 2, 1 To 1000) 'if the estimation for existing files is bigger, use a bigger number
 Set parentfolder = fso.GetFolder(Filelocation)
 fileType = Array("xlsm", "pdf", "jpg", "docx")
 ListAllFilesA parentfolder, fileType
 For Each folder In parentfolder.SubFolders
     ListAllFilesA folder, fileType
 Next
 ReDim Preserve arrFiles(1 To 2, 1 To iFile - 1)
 With Range("A2").Resize(iFile - 1, 2)
    .Value = Application.Transpose(arrFiles)
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
 End With
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Sub ListAllFilesA(strFold As Object, fileType As Variant)
 Dim fso As Object, objFile As Object, mtch As Variant
 
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    
        For Each objFile In strFold.files
           mtch = Application.match(fso.GetExtensionName(objFile.name), fileType, 0)
           If Not IsError(mtch) Then
                arrFiles(1, iFile) = objFile
                arrFiles(2, iFile) = objFile.name
                iFile = iFile + 1
           End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Fazil Oleed It doesn't matter now. Please, test the updated solution using arrays, which returns almost instantly, even for a big number of subfolders and files... I think it should be easy to adapt your existing version with what I posted. Only to declare the array having the necessary number of columns...

Comment: Thank you for your support. I am starter in VBA so have some difficulties in understanding the code.

Comment: FaneDuru , is it possible to include the file name also?

Comment: I am driving now. But tthe code returns full file name. Do you need only the file name in a different column? Not sure I got you...

Comment: Its ok take your time. Yes i need the file name in the different column

Comment: On "B:B" column?

Comment: Yes in "B:B" column

Comment: @Fazil Oleed Ok. I will adapt it in a minute... Did it. Please, test the updated code (the array faster version) and send some feedback.

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, One more question.Right now i am accessing the folder in mycomputer, what if i need access the file which is located in the server.

Comment: @Fazil Oleed: You simple adapt "Filelocation":  Change it from `Filelocation = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\VBA Practice"` to `Filelocation = "\\MyServer\server folder\Practice"`. Of course, to be used the real path... You only need to have access to the path in discussion.

Comment: @Fazil Oleed: But I would also like to remind you a simple rule: We here, when somebody answer our question, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works. Our main goal here is to make people learning. As many as possible...

Comment: Well noted.But its getting an error in the line  Set parentfolder = fso.GetFolder(Filelocation)

Comment: @Fazil Oleed:  This only means that you used a wrong path for "Filelocation". Can you access the `Filelocation` folder copying in Explorer the path you used? If not, you must do it in reverse order. Acces the network folder and copy its path to be used in code... What path string did you use for Filelocation?

Comment: Yes i am able to access the file through explorer  and i used the path as string.  let us assum this as my server "\\192.160.45.1:2221\backups" . still it shows the same.

Comment: @Fazil Oleed: I am afraid that this type of path will not work in VBScript. Try mapping the folder in discussion and then use the mapped path. Something like 'backups' showing between parenthesis (\\servername)(Z:) or a different mapping letter. Are you able to map it? You simple right click on the folder (from the network) and choose 'Map network drive...', choose a free letter and press 'Finish'. It will be accessed as "Z:", supposing that you selected 'Z'.

Comment: Hi Fane, i was trying to map the server link,but there was no luck.Could you  support me to incoporat in vba code which you had provided earlier.  If the following is the details of the server .
folder link = \\192.160.45.1:2221\backups
IP = 192.168.1.18
Username = administrator
password = 549221